# Responsive lightbox not working in iPhones

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, lightbox

We're trying to make a lightbox responsive

Here's the original CSS:

```css
#mageworxLightbox{ position: absolute;  left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 60002; text-align: center; line-height: 0; }
#mageworxLightbox img{ width: auto; height: auto;}
#mageworxLightbox a img{ border: none; }
#mageworxOuterImageContainer{ position: relative; background-color: #fff; width: 250px; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto; }
#mageworxImageContainer{ padding: 10px; }
```

Which has been edited into:

```css
#mageworxLightbox{ position: absolute;  left: 0; width: 100%; height: auto !important;  z-index: 60002; text-align: center; line-height: 0; }
#mageworxLightbox img{ width: auto; height: auto;}
#mageworxLightbox a img{ border: none; }
#mageworxOuterImageContainer{ width:80% !important; height: auto !important; position: relative; max-width: 600px; background-color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; }
#mageworxImageDataContainer{ width: 80% !important; height: auto !important; max-width: 600px; line-height: 2em;  }
#mageworxImageContainer{ padding: 10px; height: auto !important;  }
```

but the close button isn't working anymore on devices such as iPhones and I can't understand why; also in landscape mode the image is not resizing correctly.

This is our page:
http://www.arredodesignonline.com/it/letto-design-imbottito-heart.html
(to see the lightbox choose "modello letto" on dropdown and any image clicked in there will work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css to your stylesheet. Some elements have clashing layers, which causes the button to be "under" a layer so you are not clicking on a button but on some invisible layer.

```css
#mageworxImageDataContainer{
    ...
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: amazing! it's working! Two more things, when I try to open it in landscape mode the lightbox is too big, I tried to change the height in "height: 80% !important;" but I see no changes, also if I rotate my phone the black bg overlay doesn't display on every part of the page...

Comment: add `height: 90% !important;` to `#mageworxLightbox` instead of auto.. and you probably broke `#mageworxImageDataContainer` there shouldn't be 80% height I would guess. For me the overlay is okay, anyway those are different questions. Please accept answer if it helped you, but we can't do whole page css here for you :).

Comment: It's almost finished, I fixed the overlay problem, I still have some issues with landscape mode because the resize is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
device.iphone = function () {
        return !device.windows() && find('iphone');
    };

if (device.ios()) {
        if (device.ipad()) {
            addClass("ios ipad tablet");
        } else if (device.iphone()) {
            addClass("ios iphone mobile");
        } else if (device.ipod()) {
            addClass("ios ipod mobile");
        }
    }
```